# How can I calculate the height of a text selection without changing the DOM

Tags: javascript, css, dom, height, range

I am using the Range to manipulate selected text. I would like to calculate the height from where someone started selecting text to where they finished.

I have tried a span to the beginning and end of the selected range and I can accurately calculate the height form that, but it changes the DOM and prevents me form doing some other range manipulations like highlighting previously selected text.

I have also tried collecting the position of the mosedown and mosueup positions but I need an accurate height from the top of the text selected to the bottom of the text where the selection was released and thats not always the case.

So I was wondering if there was a way to calculate the height of a text selection without changing the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends which browsers you need to deal with. Here's a function that will work in IE >= 4 and browsers that support `getClientRects()` in `Range` (Firefox >= 4, WebKit since 2009, Opera). If you need support for earlier browsers, you'll need to modify the DOM, which is actually fine so long as you restore the DOM to its previous state.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W84yW/

Code:

```
function getSelectionHeight() {
    var selHeight = 0;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        selHeight = textRange.boundingHeight;
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if (!range.collapsed && range.getClientRects) {
                var startRange = range.cloneRange();
                startRange.collapse(true);
                var selTop = startRange.getClientRects()[0].top;
                startRange.detach();
                var endRange = range.cloneRange();
                endRange.collapse(false);
                selHeight = endRange.getClientRects()[0].bottom - selTop;
                endRange.detach();
            }
        }
    }
    return selHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get the selected text and place it into an hidden div with the same width and same styles, and get its height.

Comment: The question asked how to do this without changing the DOM.  A hidden div is changing the DOM.

Comment: If one were to use a separate copy of the text to do some measuring, I believe the way to do this is to put it in a visible div, but set position: absolute with left: -10000px;  That tells the browser to fully lay it out, but it won't actually ever show or cause scrollbars.

Comment: @jfriend00 true, but I suppose the OP meant "changing" the DOM at the text block; also using `display: none` won't show any scrollbars and works for this case.

Comment: Some browsers will not set heights on things that are display: none.

Comment: @jfriend00 which browsers? I just made a test with "older" browsers using this: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/Zxb5E/ Works with IE7 + 8, Safari 4, FF 3, Opera 10, all these are fairly old and they understand hidden heights, although and not so funny, is the fact that when hidden the height is different! (with the exception of FF 3), my test gets the height, hides the div, gets the height and adds two paragraphs and those are what's missin at the height, strange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the hidden DIV approach will work. Many browsers either won't have a height, or will have a height=0 for elements that are hidden like that.

Perhaps if you cloned that portion of the DOM and added it to the document with some crazy position (like left: -1000px), you could get the value.

Regardless, I think you're having to have problems getting consistent results using workarounds if the Range object doesn't provide this data for you.

Comment: hidding a div (either via `visibility: hidden` or even `display: none` can still be "seen" via javascript, try it, I did :) )